# How to rotate an image to a particular angle in Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am a beginner in  Windows Phone 7 Development, i am building an app in which i want to rotate an image to a particular angle, for example I have an image of an arrow pointing straight upwards,
I want it to be pointing at lets say 15 degrees,

How will i do it? like a user enters the angle and image gets rotated.
are there some functions available to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
<Image ... x:Name"myImg">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

in code you can rotate then by calling:

```
((RotateTransform)myImg.RenderTransform).Angle = x;
```